# How to properly create an ‘indicator column’

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, indicator

Hi so this is my example dataframe. In reality there are hundreds and thousands of players. I am trying to create a new column which indicates if the player has left or not. I’m thinking of coding if lost_on column = NaN then (new indicator col= No) and if it has a value(date) then yes? I’m not entirely sure about the best way to go about it especially to make it easier to calculate the average of players that leave us. Any help appreciated

| Name | Age | Team | Joined_on | Lost_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Martin | 19 | Zizz FC | 2019-01-13 | NaN |
| Roland | 23 | Mac FC | 2016-05-06 | 2022-01-12 |
| Matt | 21 | Tin FC | 2016-01-13 | NaN |
| Chase | 17 | Liq FC | 2020-03-09 | NaN |
| Abdoul | 24 | RBD FC | 2020-09-09 | 2021-01-01 |

Desired output (Unsure what would be more appropriate column name):

| Name | Age | Team | Joined_on | Lost_on | Player_lost(?) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Martin | 19 | Zizz FC | 2019-01-13 | NaN | No |
| Roland | 23 | Mac FC | 2016-05-06 | 2022-01-12 | Yes |
| Matt | 21 | Tin FC | 2016-01-13 | NaN | No |
| Chase | 17 | Liq FC | 2020-03-09 | NaN | No |
| Abdoul | 24 | RBD FC | 2020-09-09 | 2021-01-01 | Yes |

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use

```py
df['Player_lost'] = np.where(df['Lost_on'].isna(), 'No', 'Yes')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **np.where** to handle such problems

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Games   = ({'Name':["Ram","Shyam","Mohan","Gopal"],
           'Plays' :['2012-22-04',np.nan, '2012-21-06',np.nan]})
df = pd.DataFrame(Games)
print(df)
df['Player_lost(?)'] = np.where( df['Plays'].isnull(), 'no','yes')
print(df)
```

Comment: Please select this answer if it solve the purpose.